# Hierarchal breadcrumbs using parent/child table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, code-first

I am trying to build a diagnostic tool, so you pick one item from a list, it presents another list, you pick another, and so on - so the diagnostic questions can be buried as deep as required, eg:

Pick from:

```
Software - Microsoft - Outlook - How do I?
                               - Errors 
                     - Word    - How do I?
                               - Errors
                     - Excel   - How do I?
                               - Errors

         -Lotus 

Hardware -PC
         -Laptop 

Network  -Firewall
```

These would defined in a table as:

```
id  parent_id Title
1   0         Software
2   0         Hardware
3   0         Network
4   1         Microsoft
5   1         Lotus
6   4         Outlook
7   4         Word
8   4         Excel
9   5         How do I?
10  5         Errors
...etc
```

I've seen reference to the MVCSiteMap - I used the webforms sitemap in a similar way - but this needs to be dynamic, so that the breadcrumbs show links for:

```
Software > Microsoft > Excel > How do I? > Freeze panes
```

The table model I have is:

```
public class Forum
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int parent_id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The code in my controller is:

```
     var bc = db.Fora.FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == id);
        var cbh = new List<Forum>();
        if (bc != null)
        {
            var parent = bc.parent_id;
            while (parent != null)
            {
                cbh.Insert(0, parent);
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is build up a new list of Forums, which I can then list through and generate the breadcrumbs from.  Where I'm getting stuck is the:

```
 cbh.Insert(0, parent);
 parent = parent.Parent;
```

I suspect that either my controller code is wrong in these two lines, or my Forum model needs a reference from **parent_id** to **id**, to create the hierarchy.

Could anyone please help me complete this final piece of my puzzle?

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `cbh` is a generic List of type Forum but `parent` is if type int, you will get a type error when you `cbh.Insert(0, parent);`, what you should do is more like this:

```
var bc = db.Fora.FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == id);
var cbh = new List<Forum>(); 
while (bc != null) 
{
    cbh.Insert(0, bc);
    bc = db.Fora.FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == bc.parent_id);
}
```

Good luck.